# Hard disk problem pop up warning

Tags: hard-drive

I'm using windows 7 ultimate and it started to give me this hard disk problem warning that i had before in another OS that made me disable smart, it has been over a year since i did and my pc is running ok so my HDD is ok.

all i wanna do is disable this warning that popsup while i'm gaming or doing anything else.

thanks for your help :)

**Edit:** *(adding in info that was added as an answer instead of part of the question)*

So it's me again and i agree with both answers but i don't have the money right now to buy a new one, and yeah it could die now, i can't say. so i uploaded an image of hd tune pro scan on my HDD

[image: Screencap showing SMART errors]

Answer (score 5):

S.M.A.R.T. can be disabled in the system BIOS.

> my pc is running ok so my HDD is ok.

maybe, maybe not. these warnings are not issued without a reason. contact the manufacturer/vendor, in many cases a S.M.A.R.T. warning is sufficient reason to get a replacement.

Comment: My mobo doesn't seem to let me disable SMART :( +1 for the replacement idea, though, I didn't realise you could get a replacement before it dies!

Answer (score 4):

Your HDD is failing SMART, and so you disable the warnings? **No!**

SMART failure doesn't mean "Your HDD will fail tomorrow", or even within the next year. It means **something is wrong**. You disable that notification, you'd better have everything backed up, and be able to quickly replace that drive when it dies, and not have any critical need of it - because your HDD is no longer working optimally, whether you like it or not.

Regardless, the message should, after popping up several times, have a little "Show this notification again?" check box, which you can uncheck. But start backing up *now*, not when you're getting disk read errors and blue screens.

Answer (score 3):

The "reallocated sector count" indicates that the drive has had to move data from bad sectors into the area it reserves for this purpose, but has done so more times than is healthy - i.e. it thinks it will run out in the not too distant future than any even slightly iffy sector could result in data loss. It isn't *too* bad yet, hence that flag is registered as a warning not a failure, but you really should replace the drive sooner rather than later.

What attribute B8 is I don't know. You will probably be able to look this up in the manufacturer's online documentation if you know the exact make and model of the drive. What-ever it indicates, the drive itself thinks the situation is bad enough to consider itself failing. This probably means you should replace the drive ASAP.